# Mac - Local Html - link to a hidden folder not working

Tags: html, css, macos

I have to create a DVD containing a static HTML document referring to other documents stored in sub folders. I want the Html file to be visible, but the sub folders being hidden on each OS (Word, mac, Linux).

I have organised the like this :

- list.html
- .styles\ (folder containing multiple CSS files)
- .datas\ (folder with 200 documents accessible from the page "list.html")

Styles and datas have the attribute hidden activated on Windows. The "." at the beginning of the name of the folder allows to hide them on Mac and Linux.

The dvd works perfectly on windows: folders are well hidden and the html document is well formatted and links to others documents work like a charm.

Problem : on Mac, the html is not formatted and links to documents are all dead. Mac browsers (Safari and Firefox) seem to be unable to access the hidden folders.

Links are relative, and fully working on windows.

Is there any way to link to a folder hidden by a dot on mac ? Any idea ?

Thanks you very much, and sorry for my poor english !

Comment: Are you running on apache?

Comment: No. It is a static html file. No Html or php server.

Comment: Can you check the file and folder permissions? Folders must be readable and executable by everyone and files should be readable.

Comment: Can you post some of the HTML code where you refer to CSS files? Remeber that Linux and OSX are Unix like and therefore case sensitive while Windows isn't. Check if you are using files and paths to files with the same exact case as the links in your HTML code.

Comment: Here is the link to css : `<link rel='stylesheet' id='minimatica-css'  href='.wp-content/themes/minimatica/style.css?ver=1.0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />`

Comment: Here is the link to a pdf document : `<a class="prettylink pdf"  href=".TdP/1660-05-03-TraitedOliva.pdf">`

Comment: I Cant check permissions right now. I do not own a mac. Will try tomorow. I am not familiar with the system (I use only windows and linux..). How could I check permissions ?

Comment: And the result of the `ls` command for that file?

Comment: You can check it on linux using `ls -la` in your folder.

Comment: not tried... I do not even know haw to launch terminal on Mac... :(

Comment: Ok... :-) check [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zw7Nd67_aFw)

Comment: Thank !I will try tomorow ! I tell you the result asap !

Answer (score -2):

I think you can't do it the way you try. If you rely on the underlying OS to decide what is hidden and what not, you lose the control.

Try using a out-of-the-box xampp server like http://www.server2go-web.de or http://sourceforge.net/projects/servcd/ (newer) or http://www.stunnix.com/prod/aws/overview.shtml (also on linux and else) to run from the DVD. And then create a `.htaccess` file with an directive to allow hidden files like this.

```
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from All
</Files>
```

Or maybe just rename the folders without the leading `.`

Comment: If I remove the dot, the folders will be visible, Which I dont want to... Running a server is not an option for the persons I have to give the DVD...

Comment: But why? Whoever is interested in the files will find out.

Comment: The directories being hidden or not should be of no importance whatsoever.

Comment: I am sorry, I dont understand your answer (poor english ! My bad !)

Comment: When you have the html served as static file than the operating system the user's computer runs is responsible. So Mac OS doesn't allow the hidden folders. With an apache on DVD you will have control.

Comment: Stunnix seems to be fine, but I can't afford to launch an executable on the computer of the people concerned...